# JQuery UI datepicker onChangeMonthYear get td's

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the datepicker of JQuery UI to display additional text next to the dates. The way I am doing it is selecting all td's of the month being shown and looping through them to append the text to the required dates. So this works just fine when the datepicker has just loaded.

The problem arises when I change the month; I am using `onChangeMonthYear` to do the looping on the td's for the new selected month but the problem is the td's I am getting in `onChangeMonthYear` are of the previous month just before the new month was selected. For example if March was selected, and I change to April, `onChangeMonthYear` is giving me the td's of March. Now If I go back to March, `onChangeMonthYear` will give me the td's of April.

Here's my code for fetching the td's in `onChangeMonthYear`

```
onChangeMonthYear: (year, month, widget) => {
    // the following line of code works just fine outside of this function
    let tds = widget.dpDiv.find(".ui-datepicker-calendar td");                   
},
```

Is there something broken with the library or am I doing something wrong?

Now one weird thing I noticed:

```
onChangeMonthYear: (year, month, widget) => {
    // When I expand the contents of the following dpDiv in the browser, 
    // I get the correct td's!!
    console.log(widget.dpDiv);
    // BUT when I expand the content of the following children, 
    // I still get the td's of the previous month, how is that even possible?!?
    console.log(widget.dpDiv.children());               
},
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adp5sq1w/) to demonstrate the problem.

### UPDATE

I managed to find the [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/jolan123456789/m2uLjdxk/9/)

Comment: could you show a sample functional, it will be easier to help you

Comment: another thing **widget.dpDiv.children()** just selects the first level of childrens and the tds are included in the children with tagname table

Comment: @Frenchy I updated the post with a jsfiddle

Comment: have you try my solution?

Comment: @Frenchy sorry for the late reply. I manage to find a [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/jolan123456789/m2uLjdxk/9/)

Answer (score 0):

the `td's` are not updated when you select `td`, its the reason you have older values, i dont see event about that, so i suggest you to wait the value of tds are changed by testing the month, you could add year if needed:

```
   onChangeMonthYear: (year, month, widget) => {
      var timer = setInterval(function() {
        let $m = widget.dpDiv.find(".ui-datepicker-calendar td[data-month]");
        if (parseInt($m.first().data("month"), 10) + 1 == month) {
          console.log("clear");
          clearInterval(timer);
          addCustInfoCalendar(datePriceObj, $m);
        }

      }, 100);
    },
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let datePriceObj = {
    "3/28/2021": 300,
    "3/29/2021": 200,
    "3/30/2021": 300,
    "3/31/2021": 400,
    "4/1/2021": 300,
    "4/2/2021": 900,
    "4/3/2021": 300
  };

  $(".priceCalendar").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onChangeMonthYear: (year, month, widget) => {  
      // launch timer to check when the value of month included in td's is month
      var timer = setInterval(function() {
        let $m = widget.dpDiv.find(".ui-datepicker-calendar td[data-month]");
        if (parseInt($m.first().data("month"), 10) + 1 == month) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          addCustInfoCalendar(datePriceObj, $m);
        }

      }, 50);//every 50ms
    },
  });
  // diplay price when datepicker is first loaded
  addCustInfoCalendar(datePriceObj, $(".priceCalendar").find(".ui-datepicker-calendar td"));

});

function addCustInfoCalendar(obj, cal) {

  setTimeout(() => {
    cal.filter((_, e) => {
      let date = (parseInt(e.dataset.month) + 1) + "/" + e.innerText + "/" + e.dataset.year;
      if (/\d/.test(date) && obj[date] !== 'undefined') {
        $(e).find("a").attr('data-custom', obj[date]);
      }
    });
  }, 0);
}
```

```css
.ui-datepicker .weekend .ui-state-default {
    background: #FEA;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    width: 100%;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar > td > a {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar td a[data-custom]::after {
    content: 'Rs. ' attr(data-custom);
    display: block;
    font-size: small;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="priceCalendar">
</div>
```